# Installation of Ubunutu server 18.04 restarts after selecting target disk

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am trying to upgrade a server from Ubuntu 16 to 18. I can start the installation process described [here](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-server#0) from the bootable usb I created, but each time I reach [step 9](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-server#8), the installation starts over and brings me back to [selecting a language](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-server#3). I tried recreating the bootable usb, but that didn't help. I haven't been able to find anything on here or through googling yet. Does anyone have ideas on what is causing this problem?

**Edit:**

Thanks to ckuja's comment I was able to obtain the debug logs of the installation. The way to do it was new to me, so I'll record it here in case anyone else needs to know how to access them:

1. Press ctrl+alt+f2 to change from the graphical install screen to the command line (To get back to the graphical install screens the hotkey is ctrl+alt+f1).
2. The logs are located at /var/log/installer/subiquity-debug.log
3. You can use the scp command to send the log to a computer you have ssh access to.

Okay, here is a PasteBin link to the relevant part of the log file: https://pastebin.com/tJrti1dJ

Comment: Try to [look at the installer log](https://askubuntu.com/a/758101 "Ubuntu installation takes an hour. Is there any way to see logs?") to find out what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was a bug in subiquity, as discussed here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/subiquity/+bug/1767295

An iso posted by Michael Hudson-Doyle in that link fixed the issue for me.